# Copy Constructor with mmap address

Tags: c++, mmap

Is it possible to have a copy constructor when the class has a mmap address pointer? I am thinking that mmap has been called only once and so only one reference has been registered with the kernel.  Now two objects share that address, when 1 is deleted what happens to that address?  I guess that is cleaned-up.   If possible, will the mmap file handle the synchronization for me?

Comment: Why the negatives?  Give some feedback.

Comment: I guess , negative, because not enough information for anyone to respond to your querry.

Comment: It is a general question.  Can you put a mmap pointer into a copy constructor?  What info do you need?

Comment: I think in `mmap` you unmap the file and the file mapping is still valid till the time last one unmaps. Where is the point of deletion?

Comment: The doc says:  The munmap() system call deletes the mappings for the specified
       address range, and causes further references to addresses within the
       range to generate invalid memory references.


I understood this to mean that unmap deletes regardless of who is mapping that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is your friend here:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <memory>


std::shared_ptr<void> map_some_memory(void *addr, size_t length, 
                                      int prot, int flags,
                                      int fd, off_t offset)
{
  auto deleter = [length](void* p) {
    munmap(p, length);
  };

  // use of a custom deleter ensures that the mmap call is undone
  // when the last reference to the memory goes away.

  return { mmap(addr, length, prot, flags, fd, offset), deleter };

}

// some function that gets you a file descriptor
extern int alloc_fd();

int main()
{
  int some_file = alloc_fd();

  // allocate a shared mapping
  auto my_mapped_ptr = map_some_memory(nullptr, 100, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                       MAP_SHARED, some_file, 0);

  // cast it to sometthing else

  auto shared_ints = std::shared_ptr<int>(my_mapped_ptr, 
                                          reinterpret_cast<int*>(my_mapped_ptr.get()));

  // another shared pointer pointing to the shared ints
  auto another_share = shared_ints;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will look into this.  I am also thinking of making my class un-copyable.

Comment: @user1876942 in which case, `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter type is your friend